# breezejs: navigation property not added to entity

Tags: javascript, breeze

I've configured my WebAPI ODATA service (using 5.0.0-rc1 for $expand and $select support) and everything seems to work fine but navigation properties.

The metadata does contain my navigation property (OpenPositions on Mandate) :

[image]

Then my breeze query is the following:

```
function search() {       
    var query =  breeze.EntityQuery.from("Mandates").expand("OpenPositions").inlineCount();

    return manager.executeQuery(query.using(service)).then(function (result) {
        logger.info(result);
    }).fail(function (error) {
        logger.error(error);
    });
}
```

The WebAPI controller :

```
[Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions= AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public override IQueryable<Mandate> Get()
    {
          return new List<Mandate>() { new Mandate() { 
            Id = 1, 
            PolicyNumber = "350000000",
            OpenPositions = new List<OpenPosition>(){ 
                new OpenPosition(){ Id = 1, Amount = 2300, Mandate_Id = 1 },
                new OpenPosition(){ Id = 2, Amount = 2100, Mandate_Id = 1 }
            }},
            new Mandate() { 
                Id = 2, 
                PolicyNumber = "240000000" ,
                OpenPositions = new List<OpenPosition>(){ 
                new OpenPosition(){ Id = 3, Amount = 2500, Mandate_Id = 2 },
                new OpenPosition(){ Id = 2, Amount = 2100,  Mandate_Id = 2}
            }

            } }.AsQueryable<Mandate>();
    }
```

Nothing spectacular. But although my Mandate entities are coming back in the resultset, they do not have their OpenPositions collection.

As a test, if I add `.select("OpenPositions")` to my breeze query, then I get an error:

`unable to locate property: OpenPositions on entityType: Mandate:#WebAPINoBreeze.Models`

Why could that be ?

**[EDIT]**
query.entityType.NavigationProperties is an empty array, so that's probably a clue... It seems breeze could not build navigationproperties out of the metadata.

**[EDIT]**

foreign key added. problem still there:

```
 public class Mandate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public EStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual  List<OpenPosition> OpenPositions { get; set; }
}

public class OpenPosition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Mandate")]
    public int Mandate_Id { get; set; }
}
```

**[EDIT] **

For some reasons the [ForeignKey("Mandate")] attribute was removed at compile time (I think it's because the model class is generated. I've found a workaround and the metadata now contains the foreign key MandateId to Mandate in the OpenPositions :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must define a foreign key as Breeze associations require FKs. http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties

**[EDIT]**

Your bi-directional association should look like this:

```
 public class Mandate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual  ICollection<OpenPosition> OpenPositions { get; set; }
}

public class OpenPosition {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public int MandateId { get; set; }
    public Mandate Mandate {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added the foreign key (see update to my post) but the problem remains. Am I doing something wrong here  ?

Comment: It looks like you have a unidirectional relation. Have you used Fluent API to properly set it up?

Comment: I have rebuilt my model entirely  using OpenAccess DataBase First code generator. I do have bi-directionnal relation (Mandate -> OpenPositions and OpenPositions -> Mandate). And now instead of returning results from a IList like above I just return the OpenAccess context. Yet, breezejs still don't know about my navigation properties. Looks like a bug to me. I got it to work when I used the breeze WebApi controller. The problem occured when I stopped using the controller.

Comment: There must be something else happening. I've edited the answer showing how a bi-directional association should look like and there should be no issues there. If you create a small solution reproducing the problem, I can take a further look. Please make sure it's a small solution - send it to breeze-support@ideablade.com.

Comment: Your code looks pretty much the same as mine. I'll try to put together a repro next week.

Comment: it's really hard for me to provide a repro. However I did make some progress as I've noticed the ForeignKey attribute was removed from the model at compile time. Now that I've found the workaround, the metadata looks good (see edit in my original post), ..... BUT breeze still don't know about the OpenPositions property ! I'm clueless....