# BreezeJS lookup with navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I am starting to use breezejs for a project with a Web API 2.1 backend. I have an entity called Country that has a foreign key/navigation property to an entity called Continent.
I want to use the countries as lookup values but I also need their relationship to continents so I would like to fetch that info as well.

```
public class Country
{
        public string Iso { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Continent Continent { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a FK field called continentIso but I don't use it in code.

Currently the backend controller looks like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object Lookups() {
        var countries = _breezeRepository.Get<Country>().Include(it=>it.continent);
        //more lookups in here           
        return new { countries };
    }
```

As per the [breeze samples](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/lookup-lists) I am returning an anonymous object of entities (I have a couple more but removed them from the above to avoid confusion).

On the front end side I have a lookup repository (demonstrated by John Papa's [Building Apps with Angular and Breeze - Part 2](http://pluralsight.com/courses/build-apps-angular-breeze-part2)):

```
function setLookups() {
    this.lookupCachedData = {

       countries: this._getAllLocal(entityNames.country, 'name'),

    };
}
```

Problem is that although the sent JSON contains values for the continents, **the countries object does not contain a value or a navigation property for them.** 
I have also tried bringing the continents as a separate lookup and try joining them through breeze metadata extension as I do for connecting lookups with entities but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also have a FK field called continentIso but I don't use it in code.

Probably that's the problem as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18514357/1118323).

I would try the followings:

Make sure you have the Continent FK explicitly defined in your domain model. Eg.:

```
public class Country
{
        public string Iso { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ContinentIso { get; set; }
        public virtual Continent Continent { get; set; }
}
```

Also, in your controller, return not only the list of countries, but also the list of continents; breeze would make the binding. (not sure that the `Include` your have there is necessary).

```
[HttpGet]
public object Lookups() {
    var countries = _breezeRepository.Get<Country>();
    var countinents = _breezeRepository.Get<Continent>();
    //more lookups in here           
    return new { countries, continents };
}
```

Comment: I thought that the FK wasn't required in the model itself but only in the entity mapping, but I guess this is not the case. I have added the key and it now works with the Include.